# Search Filters Not working. Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, global-filter

Hey guys my search filters are not working for some reason. You can check in [this](http://checkingprojects.netne.net/) website! Like i dont understand why its wrong. I followed the tutorial exactly from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rv1fs0LAsI&index=18&list=PLYxzS__5yYQmX2bItSRCqwiQZn5dIL1gt) site. Please help!

Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Basic Login Form</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src = "https://rawgit.com/nirus/Angular-Route-Injector/master/dist/routeInjector.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app = "app">

<div ng-controller = "people">
    <ul>
        <h2>Names And Ages of Programmers:</h2>
          <li ng-repeat = "person in persons | filter: searchBox">
            Name: {{person.Name}}<br>
            Age: {{person.Age}}<br>
            Favorite-Color : {{person.Fav_Color}}
          </li>

    </ul>
</div>
    <div id = "searchBoxes">
      Global Search Filter : "  <input type="text" ng-model="globalSearch.$"><br>
      Name Search Filter:   <input type="text" ng-model = "globalSearch.Name"><br>
      Age Search Filter:  <input type="text" ng-model = "globalSearch.Age"><br>
      Favorite Color Search Filter:  <input type="text" ng-model = "globalSearch.Fav_Color"><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
var filex = {
    "records" : [
        {
            "Name":"Something",
              "Age":"18",
              "Fav_Color" : "Orange"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Anonymus",
            "Age" : "???",
            "Fav_Color" : "Blue"
        }


    ]
}


var app = angular.module('app',[])

app.controller('people', function($scope){
      $scope.persons = filex.records
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the input to which your filter is bound:

`<input type="text" ng-model="searchBox">`

Adding this is vital since the `ng-model="searchBox"` here is bound to your search results: `<li ng-repeat = "person in persons | filter: searchBox">` here.

Your search results are filtered based on model `searchBox`.

[JsBin example](https://jsbin.com/posojeduma/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I haven't watched the video, but according to the code you posted above: `filter: searchBox` , but `searchBox` doesn't exist! So you must bind `searchBox` to an input or sth for making the filter to work!

Comment: Thankyou @AvijitGupta i just have these dum mistakes some-times ><

Comment: Also check out the jsbin example in the updated answer.